# Refresh materialized views upon database restore

Tags: postgresql, psql, materialized-view, pg-dump

Our database (PG 12) uses a few materialized views, some depending on others. We use `pg_dump` for backups and `psql` to restore. And, we do this restore every once in a while, for example when upgrading the database version. After all these restores, the materialized views are empty and we have to refresh them `WITH DATA`, keeping an eye on the dependencies between them.

What are the options to refresh the materialized views in the best way, and what are the considerations? My ideas are along these lines:

- Perhaps there is a way to backup/restore the database including the materialized views.
- Perhaps there is some way to refresh the materialized views in a way that Postgres handles refreshing the dependencies automatically.
- Perhaps this is something the application should handle on its side - check for empty materialized views and trigger their refresh upon starting.
- Perhaps there is a better way to handle database version upgrades that does not rely on dump/restore (but still there will be cases where we need to migrate to another server).

Comment: You don't need to do backup and restore for Postgres version upgrades.

Comment: "*Perhaps there is a better way to handle database version upgrades that does not rely on dump/restore*" - [pg_upgrade](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgupgrade.html)